Referencing a Github workflow environment variable in the AssemblyInfo.tt file
My workplace has an application that we use Github to build and deploy to different environments. In the application, we want to access specifically the Github_Run_ID variable in the AssembyInfo.tt file. Can anyone explain how to do that or point me to a tutorial that can help? Or is that just not possible?

It is possible - github run id is most probably accessibly during execution of github action. So you need to store that variable, and then create IaC (terraform, I used bicep personally for Azue) script to connect to server hosting your app and store that value as env variable on that machine.

You can use
// Retrieve the environment variable
<# 
    string runId = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GITHUB_RUN_ID") ?? "0"; 
#>


Thank you to those who commented, it helped me.
In the properties for the project, Build Events -> pre-build event command line:
"$(Dir)\TextTransform.exe" "$(ProjectDir)Properties\AssemblyInfo.tt" -a "!!githubRunId!$(GITHUB_RUN_ID)"

Then in the .tt file:
string githubRunId = this.Host.ResolveParameterValue("","","githubRunId");

Which is what I found in some threads. Our problem turned out to be where we did: int.Parse(githubRunId);
The run Id was too long for int.Parse(). int64.Parse() would work, but that would still cause an issue that I'll explain below.
It was hard to figure out how to test it and get decent feedback on what wasn't working. In the github workflow output I could see that $(GITHUB_RUN_ID) was resolving, just not why it was failing.
(this is in VS 2022, though I imagine it should work on other versions)
How I was able to test it was taking the value that was resolving and replacing it for the runId variable in the command line. Then have both AssmeblyInfo.tt and AssmeblyInfo.cs open. On AssmeblyInfo.cs it showed an error for the AssemblyVersion object. It was just 1.0.0.<build>. But even leaving it as a string caused an error because it was too long for the AssmeblyVersion. For us the AssemblyVersion was only being used for cache busting(older application). So if your AssemblyVersion is important, this may not work for you.
But what we did is split the runId, as a string, into usable parts for the major.minor.version.build for the AssmeblyVersion. I know some will argue against this, but time was a factor and this worked for us.
Thanks again for the replies.
